# setting color of a link in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, hyperlink

I want to set the color of "val" in the link in below code.

```
var link = $('<a href="#" class="album">' + val + '</a><br><br>');//this is the link
link.style.color="red";//this is how iam trying to set the color of "val"
```

SO HOW TO EXACTLY DO IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
link.css({ color: 'red' });
```

But the correct and nice way would be:

```
$(".parent_element").prepend('<a href="#" class="album">'+val+'</a><br><br>');
$(".parent_element > a:first").css({ color: 'red' });
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just so you know, you can also animate the css changes:
link.animate({ color: red }, 1000);
Doing that, the code will go from default color to red in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(link[0]).css({ color: 'red'});
```

The reason for this is that `link` is not an `<a>` element - it's a set of elements: `<a>`, `<br>` and another `<br>`.

Another approach would be:

```
link.css({ color: 'red' });
```

but this will set this CSS to not only `<a>`, but both `<br>`'s as well (not a big deal though).

Comment: So you make it an element (via `[0]`) and then call the jQuery method on the DOM element?  Nope... Your second approach should work.

Comment: Sort of.  But what reason is there to use `$(link[0])` when `link` will do the same job?  The correct fix, IMHO, would be to use your second approach alongside `link[0].style.color ='red';`

Comment: @ScottSauyet - `link.css(...)` is not equivalent - it'll apply style to both `<br>` elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery(which it does seem like) go ahead with this,

**jQuery**

```
link.css("color","red");
```

Otherwise,
**JavaScript**

```
link[0].style.color = "red";
```

What you did doesn't work because link is an array. Before applying a style to it, you have to first select the first element by `link[0]` and then operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `link.style.color="red"` if `link` was an HTMLElementNode, but it isn't. It might be a jQuery object, but if you are using an older version of the library then it will return `undefined`.

First you need to fix your jQuery call. You can't create multiple elements at the top level. (You can skip this bit if you are using a sufficiently new version of jQuery).

Since there is no good reason to use a double `<br>` (it shouts "Use CSS to add a margin instead"), I've taken them out:

```
var link = $('<a href="#" class="album">' + val + '</a>');
```

Now you have a jQuery object so you can either use the jQuery method of setting CSS:

```
link.css("color", "red");
```

or get the HTMLElementNode from the jQuery object and use that:

```
link.get(0).style.color="red";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link.css("color", "red")
```

However, I think it would be better to create a css class for that and set up the color there. In Javascript/jQuery I would just add the class to the tag when needed. It is more elegant.